# Flutter CustomPaint and animationController

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-custompainter

i want to animate the charging and discharging of the capacitor ,there is an equation for charging and another equation for discharging but i want when press button, start the new painting from the end point of the previous curve but in this code when press button it start to paint from the initial point again , so the output of my code here:[image]

and this the code :

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Trace extends StatefulWidget {
  const Trace({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Trace> createState() => _TraceState();
}

@override
class _TraceState extends State<Trace> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animation;

  bool isCharging = true;
  Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 20);
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double x = screenWidth / 2;

    // Calculate the lower bound based on the screen width
    double lowerBound = (x - 80) / (x + 82);

    animation = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: duration,
      lowerBound: lowerBound,
      upperBound: 1,
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    animation.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          isCharging = !isCharging;
        });
      }),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        minScale: 0.5,
        maxScale: 5,
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: TracePainter(animation, isCharging),
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TracePainter extends CustomPainter {
  TracePainter(this.animation, this.isCharging);
  final Animation animation;
  final bool isCharging;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 89, 236, 255)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.4;
    
    final Paint paintRect = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 0.5;

    double screenWidth = size.width;
    double screenheight = size.height;

    double x = screenWidth / 2;
    double y = (screenheight / 2) - 50;
    final path = Path();
    double t = x - 80;

    double vo = 100;
    double c = 2 * 0.000001;
    double r = 500000 * 10;
    double y1= y - 50;
    double y2 = y - 50;
    double out = 0;

    path.moveTo(x - 80, y1);

    for (t; t <= ((x + 82) * (animation.value)); t += 0.01) {
      y1 = (y - 50) - vo * (1 - exp((-(t - (x - 80)) / (r * c))));
      y2 = (y - 50) - vo * (exp((-(t - (x - 80)) / (r * c))));
      if (isCharging) {
        out = y1;
      } else {
        out = y2;
      }
      path.lineTo(t, out);
    }

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(x, y - 100), width: 164, height: 104),
        paintRect);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

finally ,i want to modify this code to make the curve like this :

[image]

Comment: The loop should be based on time, not an animation value. You have to make a state for something like "elapsed time"

Comment: @pskink  every thing is ok ,but i tried to put the painting at the center of the screen  and give it a specified width and height like my provided code but i can not  as i don`t know the actual length of the painting

Comment: use `SizedBox.fromSize(child: CapacitorLevel())` then

Comment: @pskink  thanks a lot but there is a last problem that i can not speed up or slow down the animation , i tried to change the duration but it is still the same `late final controller = AnimationController.unbounded(vsync: this,duration: Duration(seconds: 20));`

Comment: @pskink this is the final code, i wish you see it : https://dartpad.dev/?id=a21d676871b2a972b2b82632a96af9c9

Comment: nice, now it looks like real capacitor :-) if you want to speed it up change `0.1` to `0 5` inside `points = simulation.leveks.map(...`